# What's the difference in these to scopes used in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a functional difference between these two scopes? Why should I choose one syntax over the other?

```
scope :graveyard, where(show_location: true, location: "graveyard")

scope :graveyard, -> { where(show_location: true, location: "graveyard") }
```

I know the latter is using a lambda, but are they functionally different?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because the latter uses a lambda, it will evaluate its parameters each time anything gets scoped. That might run a tiny bit slower, yet it would allow you to write extra code that changes those parameters, such as code that detects the current user's role and adjusts what they can view.

Without such logic, there's no functional difference.